# Determine if dictionary contains key based on a property of that key?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a custom object used as a key in a `Dictionary<CustomType, IrrelevantType>` and the custom object contains a property called `Id`:

```
public class CustomType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to check the dictionary to see if a key exists with the `Id` property equal to a supplied value. For example in semi-pseudo:

```
bool containsKey = dictionary.Contains(c => c.Key.Id == Id);
```

Everything I've tried through intellisense has ended up with something similar to:

```
bool containsKey = dictionary.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Key.Id == Id).Key.Id == Id;
```

Which is quite redundant in my opinion since I've already performed the comparison in the predicate.

---

Is there a simple, easy to understand, and yet concise way to determine if a `Dictionary<CustomType, IrrelevantType>` contains a key with a property having a specific value?

---

You can use the code below to test your answer if you'd like:

```
public class CustomType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CustomType(int id) => Id = id;
}

// Put this in the main method of a console app:
Dictionary<CustomType, int> testDictionary = new Dictionary<CustomType, int>();
testDictionary.Add(new CustomType(0), 0);
testDictionary.Add(new CustomType(1), 3);
testDictionary.Add(new CustomType(2), 5);
testDictionary.Add(new CustomType(4), 8);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (testDictionary.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Key.Id == i).Key.Id == i)
        Console.WriteLine($"A key with id '{i}' exists.");
```

The output should be:

> A key with id '0' exists.
>
> A key with id '1' exists.
>
> A key with id '2' exists.
>
> A key with id '4' exists.

Comment: You can use `Keys` collection here, like `dictionary.Keys.Where(k => k.id == id)` or `dictionary.Keys.Any(k => k.id == id)`. Or implement an equality comparison for custom object based on `id` and then use `ContainsKey` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool containsKey = dictionary.Keys.Any(c => c.id == id);
```

Although this is an `O(n)` solution, whereas dictionary key access is usually  `O(1)`.

An alternative approach would be to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer` for the dictionary which provides an equality comparison and hash function based on id:

```
class IdComparer : IEqualityComparer<YourType>
{
    public bool Equals(YourType t1, YourType t2)
    {
        return t1.Id == t2.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(YourType t)
    {
        return t.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<YourType, ValueType>(new IdComparer());
```

Then the following operation is `O(1)`:

```
bool containsKey = dictionary.ContainsKey(new YourType{ Id = id });
```

Comment: Note that this is essentially  the same what OP already has - `dictionary.SingleOrDefault(s => s.key.id == id)`... but apparently they like it more than their own code...

Comment: @AlexiLevenkov OP's code is more verbose, and is prone to a `NullReferenceException`, but would often produce the same result.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I second Johnathan's response. The code I supplied is more verbose as it doesn't result in `bool` until I tack on an second check on the `ID`, which I already did in the predicate, so why should I have to do it again?

Comment: @Taco you obviously compare with default (as your code calls `SingleOrDefault`), but you have a good point - if your struct key actually has default value that you want to find you can't do that... Bad comment on my side. Sorry.